# Do we delete answers just because they are wrong?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, deleted-answers

I am writing about https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/29029/19400.

The answer is perhaps wrong, but its position is defensible, and I don't think it should have been deleted; that's what downvotes are for.

One of the delete votes is from a moderator, so I am unable to vote to undelete it.

Mods, please undelete, or explain here. Thanks.

Comment: This has [come up before](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4103/should-incorrect-answers-be-deleted?rq=1), and the flagging system is clear that flags should be declined if they are raised solely on the grounds of wrongness. An answer that is both wrong and otherwise unsuitable is a different story, but I'm not seeing a good argument for why this particular answer qualifies as such. I'm also curious why this answer was deleted.

Comment: Undeleted, as per normal reasons. Hopefully @Karlson and JohnathanRees are a.ok. with this.

Comment: I've thought its rude and abusive, although technically correct, actually.

Comment: What's rude and abusive about the linked post?

Comment: @Bernhard that was opinion. As you can see it can be easily.overridden so no harm done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general SE policy, [wrong answers should not be flagged for deletion by users, nor should they be deleted by mods.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163730/when-should-i-delete-an-answer/163733#163733) They should just be downvoted. The author can obviously choose to delete the answer if they so wish. Thank you for bringing this up.

Since @MarkMayo undeleted the answer, I mark this as a status complete.